Should I Copy or Fork the Substrate Node Template for My Node?
We are developing our DeFi blockchain using the Substrate Node Template. Should we fork the template or copy it and use it as a standalone repository? What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Fork the template. This should be good enough for you to start.
In the future there will be the omni node which means that you will only need to have a runtime.

Thank you @bkcrh for the help
